# How to handle renegotiation in openssl (returned by SSL_read, SSL_write)

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm using openssl library on linux platform. According to the man page: `Renegotiation will happen during SSL_read/write, user should repeat that call with the SAME arguments`. So here is my scenario, right or wrong?

1: `SSL_read` returns SSL_WANT_WRITE, then I call `SSL_write` to write some data (hoping `SSL_write` can finish the handshake left by `SSL_read`)

2: `SSL_read(ssl, buf, size)` returns SSL_WANT_WRITE, then I call `SSL_read(ssl, buf2, size2)` (the `buf` arguments have been changed)

Best regards

Comment: Just keep doing what it tells you until it doesn't want anything more.

Comment: Even if the `buf` argument has to be the same? In my implementation, it's very hard to achieve this ... What I supposed is: Now that `SSL_read` returns error (with a SSL_WANT_*), data CAN'T be read into `buf`, right? So it doesn't matter if I changed the `buf` location next time I call `SSL_read`